# Matlab: calculate error value and create function out of five measurements

Tags: matlab, function, errorbar

[image]

Here are five lines that Matlab assembled when I plot my measurements. I need to create a function out of the average values from each line. I’m working with Matlab and I hope Matlab has an elegant solution for my problem. If not, I’ll take any advice.

Thanks so much in advance

Mike
 Here a small version of my code:

```
% Read text file
clc
clear all

%My Data is stored in that file.
fid = fopen(uigetfile('FILE.txt'), 'rt');

%The next lines are where I create my vectors, read the data, reshape my matrices etc
%I dont think you need to worry about it
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
nrow = 16;
ncol = 10;
row_index = [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
col_index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
matAnzahl = 1;
line = '';
naechsterunde = 1;
while strcmp(line,'')
    line = fgetl(fid);
    C = textscan(line,'%f %f %f %f');
    gewicht(matAnzahl) = C{1};
    dots(matAnzahl) = C{2};
    durchschnitt(matAnzahl) = C{3};
    absolutdurchschnitt(matAnzahl) = C{4};
    vector = fscanf(fid,'%u',160);
    t = 1;
    for i = 1:nrow
        for j = 1:ncol
            data2d(row_index(i), col_index(j)) = vector(t);
            t = t + 1;
        end
    end
    data2d;
    fgetl(fid);
    line = fgetl(fid);
    if matAnzahl > 1
        if gewicht(matAnzahl) < gewicht (matAnzahl-1)
            naechsterunde = naechsterunde + 1;
        end
    end
    matAnzahl = matAnzahl + 1;
end
matAnzahl = matAnzahl - 1;
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

%This is where I create my y- vectors that are being ploted later on.
%y1-y5 are my results and I need to get the error value out of them and
%I need a function that replaces them
%Thank you

anzahl1 = 1;
for i = 1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde
    y1(i) = absolutdurchschnitt(anzahl1);
    if anzahl1 < matAnzahl
        anzahl1 = anzahl1 + 1;
    end
end
for i = 1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde
    y2(i) = absolutdurchschnitt(anzahl1);
    if anzahl1 < matAnzahl
        anzahl1 = anzahl1 + 1;
    end
end
for i = 1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde
    y3(i) = absolutdurchschnitt(anzahl1);
    if anzahl1 < matAnzahl
        anzahl1 = anzahl1 + 1;
    end
end
for i = 1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde
    y4(i) = absolutdurchschnitt(anzahl1);
    if anzahl1 < matAnzahl
        anzahl1 = anzahl1 + 1;
    end
end
for i = 1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde
    y5(i) = absolutdurchschnitt(anzahl1);
    if anzahl1 < matAnzahl
        anzahl1 = anzahl1 + 1;
    end
end
for i = 1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde
    gewichtPlot(i) = gewicht(i);
    i = i + 1;
end
plot(gewichtPlot,y1,gewichtPlot,y2,gewichtPlot,y3,gewichtPlot,y4,gewichtPlot,y5)
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That seems to be too much !! What I understand is that you want to vectorize your loops!! If you simply provide a sample input matrix and your expected outputs, it would be easier to understand what you're  actually trying to achieve !! But till now, it seems unclear to me!

Comment: _"So I need to find a function that would replace all five"_ replace the with what??

Comment: I think the problem is much simpler than I was able to explain. Hope that helps

Comment: You posted way too much code, and also see [my (edited) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39015605/2627163) for better MATLAB practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question you can just replace your last line with:

```
plot(gewichtPlot,mean([y1; y2; y3; y4; y5]))
```

---

However, your code is written in a very "non-MATLAB" way, and I'll give you some examples:

**First**, you don't need to explicitly increase the iterator of a loop, it is done automatically. In fact, changing the loop iterator has no effect on the loop. So:

```
for i = 1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde
    gewichtPlot(i) = gewicht(i);
    i = i + 1;
end
```

can be just:

```
for i = 1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde
    gewichtPlot(i) = gewicht(i);
end
```

**Second**, in this example you don't even need a loop, this line:

```
gewichtPlot(1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde) = gewicht(1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde);
```

will give the same result, because `1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde` already takes the same elements from the vectors. This is called ["vectorization"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html?searchHighlight=vectorization).

Here is another example. I'm not sure what your variables mean, but I'm quite sure that this code:

```
anzahl1 = 1;
for i = 1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde
    y1(i) = absolutdurchschnitt(anzahl1);
    if anzahl1 < matAnzahl
        anzahl1 = anzahl1 + 1;
    end
end
```

could be switched with:

```
y1(1:matAnzahl/naechsterunde) = absolutdurchschnitt(1:matAnzahl);
```

Keep in mind that it is not a good practice to use `/` as the index, either in a loop or in a reference to a vector, because you have to be sure that the result is an integer.

**Third**, a better way to keep your data is in ordered matrices instead of different variables. So don't use `y1` to `y5`, each one in size 1-by-`matAnzahl/naechsterunde` but just one `y` in size 5-by-`matAnzahl/naechsterunde`, and reference it as `y(1,i)` to `y(5,i)`. This way the last line of your code will be: `plot(gewichtPlot,mean(y))`

---

All the above was just to be general, in your case, there is a **much** simple way to write the whole second part, where you create all the `y` vectors. Essentially 
what you do there is just to divide the `absolutdurchschnitt` vector into five equal pieces, and put them in `y1` to `y5`. So if we take example 3 from above, and the function [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) that does the exact same thing we get:

```
absolutdurchschnitt = randi(100,1,15) % some arbitrary random data
y = reshape(absolutdurchschnitt,5,[]) % create y with all the data
plot(gewichtPlot,mean(y))
```

and this will yield:

```
absolutdurchschnitt =
  Columns 1 through 11
    37    63    86    13    18    96    98    26    29    84    81
  Columns 12 through 15
    37    37    28    26
y =
    37    96    81
    63    98    37
    86    26    37
    13    29    28
    18    84    26
```

and some plot with the mean of `y` by columns against `gewichtPlot`.

There is much more to be done, but for a start, it will be good if you try to grasp these concepts.